# Oracle Partition Load Emprying another Partition

Tags: oracle11g, etl, data-warehouse

I am using Oracle 11g.  I have a list partitioned fact table, def as follows at the end of the question.  I create the partitions dynaically in the ETL process.  What's happening is that when I create and load a new partition, my one existing partition is emptied.  Anyone see why?

```
CREATE TABLE "F_PROGRAM_CONTROL_FIN_SNAPSHOT" 
   (    "L4_EPS_SKEY" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TASK_SKEY" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    ...
    ...
    "BUD_V90_HRS" FLOAT(126)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "COGNOS_BI" 
  PARTITION BY LIST ("SNAPSHOT_SKEY") 
 (PARTITION "0"  VALUES (0) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "COGNOS_BI" , 
 PARTITION "20150316070605"  VALUES (20150316070605) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "COGNOS_BI" , 
 PARTITION "20150323070904"  VALUES (20150323070904) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "COGNOS_BI" ) ;
```